# Reading in file line by line, read() grabs whole file

Tags: c, pthreads, system-calls

I'm having trouble reading in a file line by line. Apparently the `read()` system call grabs the whole file. I'm trying to read in a file with lines of variable length, however I do know that no line's length can exceed `SBUFSIZE` bytes. I'm supposed to read in each line in the file and put each line of the file onto a data structure. However my approach pushes the whole file as one line onto the data structure, which is not acceptable. Is there a modified version of `read()` which stops at the `'\n'` character?

```
#define SBUFSIZE 1025

pthread_mutex_t buffer_lock;

void* process_file(void* file_name)
{
    int input_fd;
    /* Temporary buffer, for reading in the files, one line at a time. */
    char buf[SBUFSIZE];
    memset(buf, '\0', SBUFSIZE);

    if ((input_fd = open((char*) file_name, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open the file '%s'\n", (char*) file_name);
        pthread_exit((void*) 1);  /* This is my error flag. */
    }

    while (read(input_fd, buf, SBUFSIZE)) {
        int ret;
        printf("|%s|\n", buf);
        while (true) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_lock);
            ret = stack_push(buf);
            if (ret == STACK_FULL) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_lock);
                usleep(rand() % 101);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_lock);
        memset(buf, '\0', SBUFSIZE);

        if (ret != STACK_SUCCESS) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    close(input_fd);
    pthread_exit((void*) 0);  /* This is my good flag. */
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `open()` and `read()` and not `fopen()` and `fgets()` ?  (`fgets()` will read line-by-line).

Comment: 1. I am not familiar with the other functions. 2. The assignment requires that.

Comment: In that case, you have to buffer in the input, and after each read, process any "lines" found in the input.  What ever remains after this is the first-part of the next (yet incomplete) line.

Comment: "*no line's length can exceed SBUFSIZE bytes*" or has exactly that size?

Comment: @alk It can be less that SBUFSIZE bytes (and it often is), but SBUFSIZE is the maximum number. The lines have different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

You can process line-by-line as follows:

```
char buf[SBUFSIZE + 1];
size_t bufsize = 0;

for(;;)
{
    ssize_t nread = read(input_fd, buf + bufsize, SBUFSIZE - bufsize);
    if(nread < 0)
        perror("read failed");

    bufsize += nread;
    if(!bufsize)
        break; // end of file

    const char *eol = memchr(buf, '\n', bufsize);
    if(!eol)
        eol = buf + bufsize++;
    *eol = 0;

    printf("processing line: |%s|\n", buf);
    process_line(buf);

    ++eol;
    bufsize -= eol - buf;
    memmove(buf, eol, bufsize);
}
```